# Django: Form ModelMultipleChoiceField with annotated queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

I´m trying to make a multiple choice field in a form. Instead of using the full queryset I want to annotate some values.

**The annotation**

```
productos_incluir = ProductosBase.objects\
    .filter((Q(region__region__icontains="Argentina") | Q(region__region__icontains="Todas")) & Q(estatus_contenido__id__gt=2))\
    .values("marca__marca", "producto", "packaging").annotate(variantes=Sum("producto"))\
    .order_by("marca__marca", "producto", "packaging")
```

**The form field**

```
productos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=productos_incluir, required=False)
```

**The view**

```
<div>{{ filter_form.productos }}</div>
```

**The result**

I get the list displayed in the view but I get the "Label" next to the checkbox like this:

> {'marca__marca': 'Cramer', 'producto': 'Cutter - Shark', 'packaging':
>   'Bolsa individual', 'variantes': 0.0}

**My desire**

What I want is to be able to show the labels without the field info. I guess it has to do with the queryset type change when annotating, but I can´t find how to show this.

> Cramer | Cutter - Shark Bolsa | individual

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, maybe this is what you want:

your queryset give dictionaries, so you have to iterate it using `.items`

```
{% for key, value in your_dict.items %}
   {{ key }} = {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

so in your case:

```
<p>
{% for key, value in filter_form.productos.items %}
   {{ value }} {% if not forloop.last %}|{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
</p>
```